# Mac Safari "command + c" and jquery keypress

Tags: jquery, macos, keyevent, key-events

I'm trying to implement a feature to focus `"Search"` field if typed anywhere in the `"body"`. Things are kind of working fine  as you see form jsfiddle demo. But in `MAC Safari` maching if i type `"Command + C"` it will  focus to the search field which disable copying text. Where as in `Windows` `"Ctrl + C"` works fine.

How can we avoid `"Command + C"` focusing on `"Search"` field

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/ghjo45hs/1/

Comment: This seems to _Safari_ specific rather than _Mac_ specific. It works fine in Chrome on Yosemite

Comment: Yea, i missed that, its specific to `"Mac" Safari`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with Chrome on Mac, works fine. On safari, console.log("keyCode:"+e.keyCode) log 99 when key 'c' pressed:
Try following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/s8w5do2q/1/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("body").keypress(function(e) {
       var nodeName = e.target.nodeName,
            charCode = e.which || e.keyCode,
            charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        console.log("keyCode:"+e.keyCode);
        if ((e.keyCode == 67 || e.keyCode==99) && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
            console.log("keydown-Copy");
            return;
            
        }
       console.log(e.keyCode,"keypress");;

        if ( nodeName  == 'INPUT' || nodeName == 'TEXTAREA' ) {
            return;
        }

        if (!(/[a-z0-9]/i.test(charStr))) {
            return;
        }


        $("#search").focus();
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="searchbg">
    <div>
        Search : <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
 <div>
    <div>    
        Name : <input type="text" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Address :  <textarea name="address"></textarea>    
    </div>
     Try Copy Me
 </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `e.keyCode` we need to used `charCode` . In mozilla `e.keyCode`  doesn't work
http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/ghjo45hs/4/